# `termwinsize` cannot be accessed from Python 3

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer, python

The option `termwinsize` cannot be accessed from Python 3.

**Input**

```
python3 << EOD

import vim

for window in vim.windows:
    if (window.buffer.options['buftype'] == b'terminal'):
        window.buffer.options['termwinsize'] = '10x0'

EOD
```

**Expected Result**

Success.

**Actual Result**

```
KeyError: 'termwinsize'
```

Is this an expected behavior or a bug?

(`:set termwinsize=10x0` succeeds. The options cannot be accessed only from Python 3.)

Comment: Try `window.options['termwinsize']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually the expected behavior, although that is clearly not what was intended. The key is that `'termwinsize'` is "local to window", whereas `'buftype'` is "local to buffer".

There is a slight --- but important --- distinction between "window" and "buffer". `:h windows.txt` explains this distinction in great detail. But briefly, a window is a *view* of a buffer.

Therefore, when accessing these options via the python interface, one would use
`window.options['termwinsize']`, and `window.buffer.options['buftype']` respectively.